# Laravel returning children of parents in same table using ajax request?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, relationship

Using Laravel 5.7 I have table name territory_categories. In this table I have [these Columns in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2bff.png)
how I can make a hierarchy parent and child in the same table using relationships with ajax request?

Comment: You want to show it in a table ??

Comment: yes i want to show in table

Comment: Okay so have you created model for the table `territory_categories` and the other table which has foreign key in your `territory_categories` table ?

Comment: yes I have created the model for the territory_categories but I want to assign id as foreign key to the same table column cat_parent_id if cat_parent_id is Null it is mean it is parent if it has any id it is mean it is the child of particular id

Comment: You mean to have a self join the same table ? right ?

Comment: yes I need a self join the same table

Comment: thank you so much dear brother... <3

Comment: Please, try to put those information editing your question to clarify and get an improved answer

Comment: @AshirAliButt If had accepted the answer then you revoked you answer back after a day ?

Comment: because it's not working properly and do full fill my need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this Code is working well instead of above once
this code is for Model:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('Category','parent');
}
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category','parent');
}
```

And I use to retrieve in the controller like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if($request->territory_category_name){
      $validator = $request->validate(['territory_category_name' => 'required', 'active' => 'required']);
      $validator['cat_parent_id'] = $request->cat_parent_id;
      TerritoryCategory::create($validator);
    }
    $territoryCategories = TerritoryCategory::with('parent')->get();

    $data = [];
    foreach ($territoryCategories as $key => $territoryCategory){
      $key = ++$key;
      $data[] = "
      <tr>
        <td>$key</td>
        <td class='edit' data-url='/territoryCategory/update/$territoryCategory->id' data-id='$territoryCategory->id'>$territoryCategory->territory_category_name</td>
        <td>
          ".(isset($territoryCategory->parent->territory_category_name) ? $territoryCategory->parent->territory_category_name : '<badge class="badge badge-info"> Parent </badge>')."
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='checkbox' name='active' ".($territoryCategory->active == 1 ? 'checked' : '')." disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='First group'>
            <button data-method='PATCH' data-url='/territoryCategory/update/$territoryCategory->id' data-id='$territoryCategory->id' data-name='$territoryCategory->territory_category_name' data-active='$territoryCategory->active' type='button' class='btn btn-info territoryCategoryEdit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addTerritoryCategoryModal'><i class='la la-edit'></i></button>
            <button data-url='/territoryCategory/delete/$territoryCategory->id' data-id='$territoryCategory->id' type='button' class='btn btn-danger territoryCategorydelete'><i class='la la-trash'></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      ";
    }
    return response()->json(['success'=>'New Record added successfully!','territoryCategory' => $data]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can write a simple self join for this scenario. In `territory_categories` model write a relationship.

```
public function children(){

  return $this->hasMany(territory_categories_model::class,'cat_parent_id', 'id');

}
```

> Now from controller pass data to the view and write a foreach loop. You will be able to access the hierarchy structure.

```
$data = territory_categories_model::with('children')->get();
```

> You will access the parent name also it's children now. For this case the parent will be repeating itself with each children

```
 @foreach($data as $dt)
    @if($dt->children->isNotEmpty())
       @foreach($dt->children as $child)
          <td>{{ $dt->territory_category_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $child->territory_category_name }}</td>
       @endforeach
    @endif
 @endforeach
```

Comment: dear brother I can get all parents adding this but not get childs with child td show empty when i add same code.

Comment: I think you did understand ? Have you created relationship like I have created for you ?

Comment: Look those records whose `cat_parent_id` is null will be considered as parent, but those whose `cat_parent_id` is not null will be considered as childs. It is a self join, it's already made but you can't pick it up.

Comment: thank you, dear brother, I work well actually record parent id in db is null thats why its show me empty td thanks for your help

Comment: Okay brother, i was also talking about this point. Please make upvote to answer.